# Como puedo filtrar por fecha con ApilarV?

Tags: excel, formulas

Tengo la función **=APILARV(tabla_1, tabla_2)**, que ya me ayuda bastante a connvinar ambas tablas, pero queria ver si hay alguna forma de que aparte de apilar las matrices, lo haga por fecha, digamos tengo en ambas tablas

*Tabla 1*

| Codigo | Nombre | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Flan | 14/02 |
| 23456 | Pan | 15/01 |
| 34567 | Pie | 15/03 |

*Tabla 2*

| Codigo | Nombre | Fecha | Costo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Flan | 12/03 |  |
| 23456 | Pan | 15/01 |  |
| 34567 | Pie | 11/01 |  |

Y quiero que al aplicar la funcion apilar, si se requiere alguna otra, no solo las apile en ese orden, si no que las filas de ambas tablas esten imtercaladas por fechas

Lo que busco

| Codigo | Nombre | Fecha | Costo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Pie | 11/01 |  |
| 23456 | Pan | 15/01 |  |
| 34567 | Pie | 15/01 |  |
| 12345 | Flan | 14/02 |  |
| 23456 | Pan | 12/03 |  |
| 34567 | Pie | 15/03 |  |

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que buscas, es necesario primero ordenar ambas tablas por la columna de fecha antes de aplicar la función de apilamiento. Asumiendo que estás utilizando Excel y tienes la función APILARV que deseas aplicar, puedes seguir estos pasos:

*Ordena ambas tablas por la columna de fecha.
*Apila las tablas utilizando la función APILARV.

Aquí tienes una descripción de cómo hacerlo en Excel:

Supongamos que tus tablas están en los rangos A2:C4 para la Tabla 1 y E2:H4 para la Tabla 2 (asumiendo que las columnas C y G son las fechas). Entonces, siguiendo los pasos mencionados:

*Ordena ambas tablas por la columna de fecha:
*Selecciona el rango A2:C4 (Tabla 1) y ve a la pestaña "Datos" en Excel.
*Selecciona "Ordenar" y elige "Ordenar por Columna C (Fecha)".
*Haz lo mismo para la Tabla 2 seleccionando el rango E2:H4 y ordenando por
la columna G (Fecha).

Apila las tablas ordenadas utilizando la función APILARV:

En una celda donde desees que aparezca la tabla combinada, escribe =APILARV(A2:C4, E2:H4) y presiona Enter.
Esto apilará las filas de ambas tablas intercaladas por fecha, como lo has descrito en tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar puedes usar la propia función ORDENAR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
=ORDENAR(APILARV(Tabla1;Tabla2);3;1;FALSO)
```

Eso sí, para ordenar por fecha tienes que asegurarte que sean fechas de verdad (numéricas) y no texto.

> [Función
> ORDENAR](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-ordenar-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c)